# Trying to use "mailto:" URL schema to allow users to send emails w/ errors in them

Tags: c#, serialization, mailto

In C# I have the following code:

```
body = body + ":::::" + Events.JSONToString();
body = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body).Replace('\n', '^');
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    String.Format(
        "mailto:foo@bar.com?Subject={0}&Body={1}", subject, body
    )
);
```

This works, but there are too many characters that will throw it off and terminate the body text prematurely.

Is there a formatting/escape routine that could help me preserve the data (and ideally the formatting)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to send this from the server using System.Net.Mail and avoid the possibly squirrely interaction with the users' email clients altogether?

Comment: You could just send the email if you have network access

Comment: I want to add the ability for the user to describe that is happening; and I don't want to create a UI if I don't have to.

So when they hit the button they get presented a formatted email that they can send. It is not intended for automated reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are making this part of a query string you need to use `Uri.EscapeDataString(body)` instead of `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body)`.

Comment: it looks like there is still a limit to how much text you can append, but oh well.

Comment: @BasHamer That's correct, there is a limit to the length of query string that can be handled depending on the browser/mail client. That's one of the reasons why I suggested sending your e-mail from the server instead. Also, it helps keep spammers from harvesting the address from the mailto link.